# How to use 'exist' for multiple values in postgres?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I have been trying to figure out how I can combine multiple values to see if one of them returns True then it exists. Meaning that if A is True and B is False = Return True. If both are False then of course we return = False.

What I have currently done is:

```
dict_tuple = {"type": "fruit", "link": link, "store": store}

sql_query = "SELECT store, link FROM public.fruit_urls WHERE link_type=%(type)s AND link=%(link)s AND store=%(store)s union SELECT store, link FROM public.store_items WHERE link=%(link)s AND store=%(store)s"
```

which seems to work but I would like to convert the query to use exists instead since I do check if its in the database or not.

I managed to solve to do one check:

```
sql_query = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT store, link FROM public.store_items WHERE link=%(link)s AND store=%(store)s)"
```

but how can I combine both

1. `"SELECT EXISTS (SELECT store, link FROM public.store_items WHERE link=%(link)s AND store=%(store)s)"`
2. `"SELECT store, link FROM public.manual_urls WHERE link_type=%(type)s AND link=%(link)s AND store=%(store)s"`

together and then return if one of them are in the database or not

Comment: Simply put `select exists(...)` around your initial `UNION` query.

Comment: Do you mean like this? ```SELECT EXISTS ("SELECT store, link FROM public.fruit_urls WHERE link_type=%(type)s AND link=%(link)s AND store=%(store)s union SELECT store, link FROM public.store_items WHERE link=%(link)s AND store=%(store)s")``` ? @VadimLanda

Comment: Yes, exactly, only without the quotes.

Comment: Oh... That was as easy as that. I did not know that :) @VadimLanda - If you want, you could do that as an answer and Iwill mark it as the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just surround `SELECT ... UNION SELECT...` with `SELECT EXISTS(...)`:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
  SELECT store, link FROM public.fruit_urls WHERE link_type=%(type)s AND link=%(link)s AND store=%(store)s 
  UNION 
  SELECT store, link FROM public.store_items WHERE link=%(link)s AND store=%(store)s)
```